# Regular Expression: Split String,

Tags: r, regex, tidyr

Real elementary question, but I have a single column containing multiple rows of dirty data, I've been looking to clean it up using regular expressions, though admittedly, this mightn't be the best approach.

- All codes consist of four digits, and all quantities consist of a digit between one and three.
- All cells contain at least one code consisting of four digits. (1234)

  - Some cells contain multiple codes. (4321 9876)
  - Some cells contain both codes and quantities, separated by a single white space, which can be both preceding and trailing.
    (12 1234) (1234 12)
  - Some cells contain a combination of all of the above(1234 12 9876 1234 12)
  - Some cells contains a combination of all three, plus some random digits which proved impossible to strip away. (1234 12 9876 1234 12 1)

I'm looking to split these strings, and append them into two columns: Quantity, Code.

```
library(tiydyr)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(string = c("1234" , "4321 9876", "199 1234 5678 12", 
                                                  "1234 12 9876 1234 12 1"))

df <- extract(df, string, c("Quantity","Code"), "(\\d{1,3})(\\d{4})" )
```

And I'm getting the following error:

> Error: Invalid column specification

As noted in the comments what I'm looking to do requires multiple regexes. If somebody could point me in the right direction as to how to split just one, like [Quantity, Code], it would be incredibly helpful.

```
+-------------------------------+
|Row  Dirty String              |
+-------------------------------+
| 1  1234                       |
| 2  4321 9876                  |
| 3  199 1234 5678 12           |
| 4  1234 12 9876 1234 12 1     |
+-------------------------------+
```

(Ideal)

```
+---------------------------+
| Row Quantity  Code        |
+---------------------------+
| 1     1       1234        |
| 2     1       4321        |
| 3     1       9876        |
| 4    199      1234        |
| 5     12      5678        |
| 6     1       1234        |
| 7     12      9876        |
| 8     12      1234        |
+---------------------------+
```

Comment: You don' need `df$string` it should be `extract(df, string, `  It is not clear what your expected output

Comment: So what about cases like the fourth row of your example, `"1234 12 9876 1234 12 1"`? You did not list that in your ideal output.

Comment: You cannot do that with a single regex. Note you want to get `1` as quantity for `"1234"`, I guess because there is no quantity value.

Comment: Sorry, will changes asap.

Comment: the first argument of `tidyr::extract` must be a data frame, hence the error. should be `df <- extract(df, string, c("Quantity","Code"), "(\\d{1,3})(\\d{4})" )`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, and I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: I don't see any clear rules as to how separate those quantities